# What is the name of this kind of contract?

Tags: bsc, bscscan

Im new to this. I am just wondering whats the name/type of this smart contract?
Its on Binance smart chain network. 0x00000000002764f05A072dF5D7A67C852c6B1762 that is the contract.
From my understanding that is contract to buy token early and sell the token early. Is it possible to re create those contract and use it for my own? Could someone help me to recreate those smart contract ?

Thank you

Note: I tried to decompile it with online evm and use online solidity decompiler but i could not do it as i have very little knowledge about smart contract. Then I also got scammed by following tutorial on youtube.

Comment: Some kind of MEV bot. Don't trust tutorials and make some on your own. Study solidity and how flashbots work first.

Comment: Whats MEV bot? Whats MEV stand for?  Where can i learn basic solidity with no background at all ? Do u have recomend channel on utube ?

Comment: Just google MEV bot. You can learn solidity by reading the docs

Comment: Just googled mev bot. Thank you for the guidance. But for several days im watching the contract interactions is quite advance thou. It buy every new token that just add their LP and just before the owner of token changed it into honeypot or remove lp, the contract will always pull out their money before the token got rugged. Thats very convinient imo..